# Why the dimension of kernel doesn't divides the dimension of the vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Suppose $V$ is $n$ dimensional vector space. Let $T: V\rightarrow W$, So $\ker(T)$ is a subspace of $V$. Subspace is also a subgroup with additive operation. So $\ker(T)$ is a subgroup of $V$. By Lagrange theorem, $|\ker(T)|$ divides$|V|$. But in general the dimension of kernel doesn't necessarily divides the dimension of the vector space.

So does that mean the symbol $|V|$ doesn't mean the dimension, but means how many vectors inside this vector space $V$, similar for $|\ker(T)|$, so both of $|V|$ and $|\ker(T)|$ are infinite. If this reasoning is correct, then what is the meaning of "dimension", I mean if convert this "dimension" into the terminology in group theory, what is the analogy? Thank you.

Comment: To be honest, the question is a bit surprising, because usually you learn about vector spaces much earlier than about groups.

Comment: A non-trivial kernel Ker(T) has an infinite cardinality (not its dimension !). You cannot apply Lagrange theorem to infinite groups, that's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of quotients dimension tells us something about chains of quotients than it does individual quotient operations. For example say we start with $\mathbb{R}^n$ as an abelian group. Now pick a vector and quotient its span which gives us the space $\mathbb{R}^n/\mathbb{R} \cong \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$. We can now iterate by picking a vector in $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ and quotienting out its span giving us a space isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{n-2}$ and so on. Eventually this process stabilizes, because $\mathbb{R}^0= \{0\}$ and after that we're out of vectors to choose from. This gives us a chain of homomorphisms  $$\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n-1}\rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \rightarrow 0$$

and here we see the length of this chain is related to the dimension of the space. This all works nicely because vector spaces have nice properties but once we move from fields to rings or start working in non-abelian groups complications arise. One simple way to see this is that finite groups can have complicated substructures for its quotient but this chain of homomorphisms would quotient it out in a single step. This leads us to consider the finite and infinite portions separately when defining its dimension.

Answer (score 3):

Lagrange's theorem is about cardinality, not dimension. For example, $\mathbb{R^n}$ is clearly an infinite space, but it has a finite dimension $n$ over $\mathbb{R}$. This means that each basis has $n$ vectors. (so each basis is finite, although the space itself is not) Actually, the only finite nontrivial spaces are finite dimensional spaces over a finite field.

If you are familiar with groups, you probably know that similarly, an infinite group might be finitely generated. However, most groups don't have any "basis" or "dimension". Only free groups have something similar. Free abelian groups as well.

Answer (score 1):

The dimension is a logarithmic function of the space, as you can see in the expression ${\bf R}^n$. So when you divide, dimensions substract.

$${\bf R}^n / {\bf R}^d \simeq {\bf R}^{n-d}$$
up to isomorphism.

Comment: What do you mean "divide"? do you mean quotient space? What I have in mind is since the mapping $T: V \rightarrow W$ is a homomorphism, the quotient group $V/\ker(T)$ is isomorphic to $\text{Image}(T)$, which gives $\dim(V/\ker(T))=\dim \text{Image}(T)$

Comment: Yes, exactly. As you said, the quotient of a vector space by the kernel of a morphism is isomorphic to the image.

Answer (score 0):

If $V$ contains only finitely many vectors then the cardinality of $\ker(T)$ divides the cardinality of $V$. The dimension of $V$ is the maximum number of linearly inependent vectors in $V$. which is a comletely different idea from the number of vecors in $V$.